# Behaviour of list comprehension with if-else

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have done this list comprehension to read a bunch of "pkl" files:

```
a = [pd.read_pickle("my_file"+str(i)+".pkl" for i in range(1, 18) if os.path.exists("my_file"+str(i)+".pkl")]
```

This is the only way I get it to work. If I add an `else` clause after the if it doesn't work. If I put the `if` clause before the loop it doesn't work. Could you explain why? If I do:

```
a = [pd.read_pickle("my_file"+str(i)+".pkl") if os.path.exists("my_file"+str(i)+".pkl") else print(i) for i in range(1, 18)]
```

This **doesn't** work, as opposed in many answers about list_comprehensions where that structure works.

Thanks.

Comment: `(todo1 if condition else todo 2 for item in dataset)` this is the correct syntax to use comprehension if you want to add `else part`

Comment: yep, if cluases go last if they are solo, if else goes after operation. A bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: I edit the question to show more details.

Comment: Aren't you missing a closing `)` before the `if` statement? So `a = [pd.read_pickle("my_file"+str(i)+".pkl") if os.path.exists...`?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [pd.read_pickle("my_file"+str(i)+".pkl" if os.path.exists("my_file"+str(i)+".pkl") else your_alternate_value for i in range(1, 18)]
```

Or as I prefer to format it to prevent such long lines:

```
a = [
            pd.read_pickle("my_file"+str(i)+".pkl"
        if os.path.exists("my_file"+str(i)+".pkl")
        else your_alternate_value
    for i in range(1, 18)
]
```

List comprehension are a little hard for me to figure how to format. There might be another way that I would prefer, but it hasn't come to me yet.

## Explanation

A list comprehension translates to a format like this

```
some_list = []
for ...:
    for/if ...
        ...
            ...
            some_list.append(something)
```

It's however many blocks you want, but only going deeper. Any block can contain only another block or the final appended value. Now, this makes sense when you consider that a list comprehension has no indentation. If you have two `if` blocks, how does the comprehension know which one the `else` belongs to?

The secret of my solution is that it isn't another block; it's part of what's being appended. The if/else is one expression, comparable to the ternary operator in other languages. Here's what's going on:

```
some_list = []
for ...
    some_list.append(something if blah else some_other_thing)
```

That's why the if/else is at the beginning.